# Id variable does not work when I want to use it as reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var lightcount = 0;        
    $("#addlight").click(function(){
        var domElement = $('<div id="L' + lightcount +'" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center"><div class="rumbox"></div><button id="onoff" type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success">  ON  </button></div>');
        var lid= $(domElement).attr("id");
        console.log(lid);

        $(lid).after(domElement);
        lightcount++
    });
```

I have a function that creates a new lightbox when clicking a button.
I want the new lightboxes to be places after current one.

I have a variable for the div id that is incremented for every new lightbox.

So instead of `$("#L3").after(domElement)` (which actually works),
I want to use my variable lid: `$(lid).after(domElement);` But this does not work.

Comment: `$(domElement)` I don't think $ is needed as domElement is already a jquery object

Comment: I think you should attach the "div" in domElement variable to the actual  DOM. and try calling after( ) function.

Comment: That time $(lid) is also not in dom we need to append it

Comment: You're trying to append something not yet in the dom after itself, also not yet in the dom.

Comment: I got it wrong, `lid` is ID of some other element which is probably in the `DOM`, In that element, you are appending `domElement`. Do create a fiddle to demonstrate your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the dom first and use the after function. lid will be having only id value you need to prepend "#" to that.

```
 var lightcount = 0;        
    $("#addlight").click(function(){
        var domElement = $('<div id="L' + lightcount +'" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center"><div class="rumbox"></div><button id="onoff" type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success">  ON  </button></div>');

        //Add it to dom . Change the id
        $("#test").append(domElement)

        var lid= $(domElement).attr("id");
        console.log(lid);

        $("#"+lid).after(domElement);
        lightcount++
    });
```

Comment: Why to append it ? OP wants to use it @ `$("#"+lid).after(domElement);`

Comment: $(domElement).attr("id") will return "L0" not "#L0". To use it as a ID selector you need to prepend ''#"

Comment: That is a different story, first answer which is deleted mentioned the same... I am asking about `append` operation.. Why do we need that ?

Comment: @Rayon Seriously, I dont understand. How a selector will pass if there is no such element in the dom. Can you explain? Am I missing anything>

Comment: "domElement" is a jquery object(Not a dom element). To perform operations like after on the dom element, object should be inserted or present in the dom. BTW the deleted answer was partially correct

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy — I think there is a element in the `DOM` having is identical to `lid`(Forget the specs about UNIQUE ID :( ) hence..

Comment: Thanks! I guess the  $("#test"), should be the parent div? Correct?

Comment: @A.E: yes parent Div

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$("#" + lid).after(domElement);
```

Comment: OP just created the element, He haven't inserted it into the dom. So the selector wont return anything.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy — Why will one append it to DOM ?